# Import mocks over file if testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, jestjs

I am using Jest framework for testing a React Native application.
I would like to import by default `__mocks__/store.js` over the other store, which is required in both `__tests__` and `app`. However it seems that only `__tests__` files are loading the mock version.

```
__tests__
  index.js
app
  __mocks__
    store.js
  sagas.js
  store.js
```

It seems that sagas.js is not using the store mock singleton.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved a little ago. Wanted to share in case that it is useful for someone else.

It is just needed to call explicitly to `jest.mock('../app/store')` from `__tests__`.

EDIT: Check this answer to learn how to do it recursively: [How can I test a store singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566719/how-can-i-test-a-store-singleton/41674840#41674840)

Answer (score 0):

I use [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to fake Node `require` / ES5 `import`

Comment: Could you add an example? As I read their docs, it seems a little unscalable with Jest